# What is Fourier Transform of $\phi(x,y) = 2x $

Tags: fourier-analysis, mathematical-physics

How to calculate Fourier transform of this 2D function?

> $\phi(x,y)=2x$
>
> for $-1<=x <= 1 ; and -1<=y<=1$

and

> $\phi(x,y)=0$    ; otherwise

I tried like this:

$\psi(u,v) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(x,y)e^{-2\pi i(ux+vy)}dxdy$

which can be written as, by taking $\alpha = 2\pi iu$ and $\beta=2\pi iv$:

$\psi(u,v)= [2\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-\alpha x}dx][ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\beta y} dy$]

**The first integral does not converge** (I checked this using Mathematica).

I know that we can find FT numerically which I do **not** want to do right now.

Comment: why integrate over the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$? It should be from........... ?

Comment: @CheeHan : That's definition of FT

Comment: But what is the domain of your function?

Comment: its basically a circle of radius 1 and with centre at (0,0) as mentioned above: x goes from -1 to 1 and same for y. For other values of (x,y) which are outside this circle, $\phi(x,y)=0$

Comment: Be careful. That is not what is writen above. It is not the same having $(x,y)\in[−1,1]\times[−1,1]\ $  (a square) or $(x,y)\in\{(x,y); x^2+y^2\le1\}$ (a circle). The former is what you seem to be asking in your question (and, hence, my answer), while the latter is what you mention in your comment.

Comment: @AugSB : Yes. I want the latter case i.e. $x^2+y^2<=1$ What will be the change in your answer then ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $\phi(x,y)=0$ if $(x,y)\not\in[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$. Thus,

$$\psi(u,v) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(x,y)e^{-2\pi i(ux+vy)}dxdy = \int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\phi(x,y)e^{-2\pi i(ux+vy)}dxdy.$$

I guess you are able to continue from here.